# 3 background image to view without content

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a banner without content and it work using `height` tag but when I tried to minimize my website the last image won't follow.
Do you have any idea what to do with this?

[image]

```
.banner{
    background: url(../img/bg2.png) top no-repeat, url(../img/bg3.png) bottom no-repeat, url(../img/banner.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 485px;
}
```

Comment: `background-size: cover`

Comment: @Roy it won't work

Comment: why don't you use `:before` & `:after` for your **1st** and **2nd** images? 

simply you can position them absolute to top and bottom to fix theme correctly

Comment: i don't know how to use `:before` & `:after`

Comment: share your screen short at minimize the website .... and you want these 3 images always on full screen at any height
??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a responsive banner, you shouldn't write a fixed height. You should read about aspect ratios https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp.
And set background-size: contain;

Comment: Thanks the aspect ratio works well. I add `position:relative;` and `padding-top: 37%;`